# Why does fetch in javascript return net::ERR_FAILED in every case?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm trying to ask an API with the fetch command:

```
    fetch('http://fr1.api.radio-browser.info/json/tags');
```

and chrome keep answer me :

```
net::ERR_FAILED

TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

I don't understand what's wrong with this simple code. Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Check the network tab to see what the reason is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you catch the error after calling `fetch`, you should see a more descriptive error:

```js
// HTTP
fetch('http://fr1.api.radio-browser.info/json/tags')
    .catch(console.error);
```

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fr1.api.radio-browser.info/json/tags' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://fr1.api.radio-browser.info/json/tags'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Try fetching using `https`:

```js
// HTTPS
fetch('https://fr1.api.radio-browser.info/json/tags')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
```